# ГАР (ФИАС) применение дельт

Tags: xml

Всем привет!

Вопрос для тех кто работал с ГАР. На сайте ФНС не очень полное описание файлов. Есть ли какие-то особенности по применению дельт? Раньше дельты содержали файлы, отмеченные буквой "D", которые содержали идентификаторы строк для удаления и файлы без "D", которые содержали строки для обновления, если такие ИД в БД уже были и для вставки, если их не было.
Если кто-то шарит в теме, буду благодарен за ответ.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, сейчас удаление не предусмотрено вообще. Записи безусловно добавляются в таблицы. В большинстве таблиц каждая запись содержит признаки ISACTUAL (актуальность) и ISACTIVE (активность). Если запись (или несколько) для добавляемого объекта уже существует, то в ней в поле ISACTUAL записывается ноль. Единица должна быть только у одной записи для объекта - если верить описанию, конечно. В некоторых таблицах имеется только дата действия записи в поле ENDDATE. Скачайте "Сведения о составе информации Государственного адресного реестра" и смотрите. Там описано.

Comment: @Akina, К сожалению, ничего там не написано. Там 22 документа для каждой таблице, у которых описание почти под копирку и в конце описание полей. Если для фиас в формате dbf они хотябы уделили пару абзацев этой теме, то для гар я ничего не нашел. isactual и isactive, на сколько, я помню были и в ФИАС.

Comment: Вот в самой последней таблице, где список полей, есть некоторые пояснения по их назначению. Это максимум того, что удаётся обнаружить на сайте :(